# Order-independent Deep Learning Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a dataset with parallel time series. The column 'A' depends on columns 'B' and 'C'. The order (and the number) of dependent columns can change. For example:

```
            A   B    C
2022-07-23  1  10  100
2022-07-24  2  20  200
2022-07-25  3  30  300
```

How should I transform this data, or how should I build the model so the order of columns 'B' and 'C' ('A', 'B', 'C' vs 'A', C', 'B'`) doesn't change the result? I know about GCN, but I don't know how to implement it. Maybe there are other ways to achieve it.

UPDATE:

I want to generalize my question and make one more example. Let's say we have a matrix as a singe observation (no time series data):

```
   col1 col2  target
0     1    a      20
1     2    a      30
2     3    b      30
3     4    b      40
```

I would like to predict one value 'target' per each row/instance. Each instance depends on other instances. The order of rows is irrelevant, and the number of rows in each observation can change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a permutation invariant operation on the columns.

One way of achieving this would be to apply column-wise operation, followed by a global pooling operation.
How that achieves your goal:

- column-wise operations are permutation [equivariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map); that is, applying the operation on the columns and permuting the output, is the same as permuting the columns and then applying the operation.
- A global pooling operation (e.g., max-pool, avg-pool) across the columns is permutation invariant: the result of an average pool does not depend on the order of the columns.
- Applying a permutation invariant operation on top of a permutation equivariant one results in an overall permutation invariant function.

Additionally, you should look at self-attention layers, which are also permutation equivariant.

What I would try is:

1. Learn a representation (RNN/Transformer) for a single time series. Apply this representation to `A`, `B` and `C`.
2. Learn a transformer between the representation of `A` to those of `B` and `C`: that is, use the representation of `A` as "query" and those of `B` and `C` as "keys" and "values".

This will give you a representation of `A` that is permutation invariant in `B` and `C`.

---

**Update <sub>(Aug 3<sup>rd</sup>, 2022)</sub>:**

For the case of "observations" with varying number of rows, and fixed number of columns:
I think you can treat each row as a "token" (with a fixed dimension = number of columns), and apply a [Transformer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html) encoder to predict the target for each "token", from the encoded tokens.

Comment: Thank you! I have another Question. If I have a tensor m x n as a single observation (no time data) and would like to predict a tensor of size m (one value for each row). The order for those m input tensors (rows) is irrelevant. Should I use the same strategy?

Comment: @Thank you very much for your help. The first version works. I try to implement the multilabel version and posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73261021/multi-instance-classification-using-tranformer-model).