# Multi-instance classification using tranformer model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transformer-model

I use the transformer from this [Keras documentation example](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/) for multi-instance classification. The class of each instance depends on other instances that come in one bag. I use transformer model because:

> It makes no assumptions about the temporal/spatial relationships across the data. This is ideal for processing a set of objects

For example, each bag may have maximal 5 instances and there are 3 features per instance.

```
# Generate data
max_length = 5
x_lst = []
y_lst = []
for _ in range(10):
    num_instances = np.random.randint(2, max_length + 1)
    x_bag = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(num_instances, 3))
    y_bag = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=num_instances)
    
    x_lst.append(x_bag)
    y_lst.append(y_bag)
```

Features and labels of first 2 bags (with 5 and 2 instances):

```
x_lst[:2]

[array([[8, 0, 3],
        [8, 1, 0],
        [4, 6, 8],
        [1, 6, 4],
        [7, 4, 6]]),
 array([[5, 8, 4],
        [2, 1, 1]])]

y_lst[:2]

[array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0]), array([0, 0])]
```

Next, I pad features with zeros and targets with -1:

```
x_padded = []
y_padded = []

for x, y in zip(x_lst, y_lst):
    x_p = np.zeros((max_length, 3))
    x_p[:x.shape[0], :x.shape[1]] = x
    x_padded.append(x_p)

    y_p = np.negative(np.ones(max_length))
    y_p[:y.shape[0]] = y
    y_padded.append(y_p)

X = np.stack(x_padded)
y = np.stack(y_padded)
```

where `X.shape` is equal to `(10, 5, 3)` and `y.shape` is equal to `(10, 5)`.

I made two changes to the original model: added the Masking layer
after the Input layer and set the number of units in the last Dense layer to the maximal size of the bag (plus 'sigmoid' activation):

```
def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0):
    # Attention and Normalization
    x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
    )(inputs, inputs)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(res)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
    return x + res

def build_model(
    input_shape,
    head_size,
    num_heads,
    ff_dim,
    num_transformer_blocks,
    mlp_units,
    dropout=0,
    mlp_dropout=0,
):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    inputs = keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0)(inputs) # ADDED MASKING LAYER
    x = inputs
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):
        x = transformer_encoder(x, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format="channels_first")(x)
    for dim in mlp_units:
        x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(5, activation='sigmoid')(x) # CHANGED ACCORDING TO MY OUTPUT
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

input_shape = (5, 3)

model = build_model(
    input_shape,
    head_size=256,
    num_heads=4,
    ff_dim=4,
    num_transformer_blocks=4,
    mlp_units=[128],
    mlp_dropout=0.4,
    dropout=0.25,
)

model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),
    metrics=["binary_accuracy"],
)
model.summary()
```

It looks like my model doesn't learn much. If I use the number of true values for each bag (`y.sum(axis=1)` and `Dense(1)`) as a target instead of classification of each instance, the model learns good. Where is my error? How should I build the output layer in this case? Do I need a custom lost function?

UPDATE:
I made a custom loss function:

```
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    mask = tf.cast(tf.math.not_equal(y_true, tf.constant(-1.)), tf.float32)
    y_true, y_pred = tf.expand_dims(y_true, axis=-1), tf.expand_dims(y_pred, axis=-1)
    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction='none')
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(bce(y_true, y_pred), tf.float32) * mask)

mask = (y_test != -1).astype(int)
pd.DataFrame({'n_labels': mask.sum(axis=1), 'preds': ((preds * mask) >= .5).sum(axis=1)}).plot(figsize=(20, 5))
```

And it looks like the model learns:
[image]

But it predicts all nonmasked labels as 1.
[image]

@thushv89 This is [my problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584029/predict-parallel-time-intervals). I take 2 time points: t1 and t2 and look for all vehicles that are in maintenance at the time t1 and for all vehicles that are planned to be in maintenance at the time t2. So, this is my bag of items. Then I calculate features like how much time t1 vehicles have already spent in maintenance, how much time from t1 to the plan start for t2 vehicle etc. My model learns well if I try to predict the number of vehicles in maintenance at the time t2, but I would like to predict which of them will leave and which of them will come in (3 vs [True, False, True, True] for 4 vehicles in the bag).

Comment: Sigmoid with binarycrossentropy needs the output layer to have 1 neuron (since it's binary). If you really want five potential outputs, use `softmax` with `sparsecategoricalcrossentropy`. That's why you're not seeing any learning.

Comment: Shouldn't your labels be (64,)? It looks like maybe you could be passing a 2D array of labels and it's getting flattened? How are you defining your inputs and passing them to your model? The original question suggests the labels are

Comment: No. I have max 355 instances per bag  and correspondingly 355 labels per learning unit. Each of those labels are binary. The part of the data is masked.

Comment: Ahh, ok in that case, you were right with having sigmoid and binarycrossentropy. Put those back to the original. Try changing your monitored metric from `accuracy` to `BinaryAccuracy` on this line: `metrics=["binary_accuracy"]`

Comment: @Djinn The metric looks good, but it looks like the model learns to distinguish between non-masked and masked targets. It sets non-masked targets to 1 and masked to 0. It looks like a need a custom loss.

Comment: Is it only doing two classes? Aren't you using 355 neurons in the final dense layer?

Comment: Maybe try using the loss `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` with the metric `sparse_categorical_accuracy`.

Comment: @MykolaZotko, are you able to share some context/usecase to attach to this problem? It might be easier to think that way. Also, with the sample data provided, would you think if the model can learn correct labels from the provided data, that'd be a good sign?

Comment: @MykolaZotko what do you mean by "model learning the wrong thing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three important improvements:

1. Replace the GlobalAveragePooling1D layer with the Flatten layer.
2. Add a custom loss function to exclude target padding from calculation (already added to my question) and a custom metric function if you want to see the real metric.
3. Add an attention_mask to the MultiHeadAttention (instead of Masking layer) to mask the padding.

Comment: Quick question, do you want to improve the accuracy of your model? Or simply fix the error like you simply did :P

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple add-on to @Mykola_Zotko 's improvement answer to those new users who are learning deep-learning with `keras` and `tensorflow`.

---

> Remove the GlobalAveragePooling1D

For context, this `GlobalAveragePooling1D` is basically a Global average pooling operation for temporal data. So basically when you remove this method call, you are removing the "pooling" operation, or in simpler terms by @Mykola_Zotko:

> ... you get a two-dimensional tensor with the max number of items in the first dimension (5 in my case) for free in the output

The alias is:

```
tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool1D
```

and the code for this method:

```
tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D (
    data_format = "channels_last", **kwargs
)
```

The source for this can be found on:

- [Github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/v2.9.0/keras/layers/pooling/global_average_pooling1d.py#L25-L96)
- [TensorFlow 1 version](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling1D)
- [TensorFlow.org doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling1D)

---

> Add a custom loss function

What a loss function simply does is to "to generate the quantity that a model should seek to minimize during training time". [Source](https://pythonguides.com/tensorflow-custom-loss-function/)

Or in other terms:

> In mathematical optimization, statistics, machine learning and Deep Learning the [Loss Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) (also known as Cost Function or Error Function) is a function that defines a correlation between a series of values and a real number. That number represents conceptually the cost associated with an event or a set of values. In general, the goal of an optimization procedure is to minimize the loss function. [Towardsdatascience - custom loss function in tensorflow](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-loss-function-in-tensorflow-eebcd7fed17a)

---

> Add an attention_mask to the MultiHeadAttention

Alias:

```
tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention
```

Code for the method:

```
tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
    num_heads,
    key_dim,
    value_dim=None,
    dropout=0.0,
    use_bias=True,
    output_shape=None,
    attention_axes=None,
    kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
    bias_initializer='zeros',
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None,
    bias_constraint=None,
    **kwargs
)
```

Source on:

- [Github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/v2.9.0/keras/layers/attention/multi_head_attention.py#L122-L515)
- [TensorFlow.org doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention)

---

Previous improvements that were made to the code:

- `metrics=["accuracy"]` to `metrics=["binary_accuracy"]`

```
model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),
    metrics=["binary_accuracy"],
)
```

- Using `Crossentropy` in the custom loss function