# Custom categorical loss function for a variable number of labels

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

How can I build a custom loss function for a variable number of labels:

```
y_true = np.array([[0., 1., -1., -1.],
                   [1., 0., 1., -1.]])

y_pred = np.array([[0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1],
                   [0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.5]])
```

In this example, we have a batch size equal to 2 and a variable number of labels (with max length of 4) for each sample. -1 values in y_true is a mask and I would like to calculate a binary crossentropy between other values (`[[0., 1.], [1., 0., 1.]]` and `[[0.3, 0.5], [0.4, 0.3, 0.7]]`). Thank you!

I can only create such a function for 1d tensor:

```
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    bools = tf.math.not_equal(y_true, tf.constant(-1.))
    n = tf.math.count_nonzero(bools)
    y_true = y_true[:n]
    y_pred = y_pred[:n]
    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
    return bce(y_true, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just compute your loss point wise (pass `reduction=none`) and use your matching of -1 as a mask.

```
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    mask = tf.cast(tf.math.not_equal(y_true, tf.constant(-1.)), tf.float32)
    y_true, y_pred = tf.expand_dims(y_true, axis=-1), tf.expand_dims(y_pred, axis=-1)
    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction='none')
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(bce(y_true, y_pred), tf.float32) * mask) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)
```

Depending how you want to average you might want to do per row sum of mask to normalise each loss separately etc.

Comment: Thank you! As I understand if I add a Masking layer to my NN it masks only features and not labeles. So there are no workaround here and I need this custom function? I try to solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73261021/multi-instance-classification-using-tranformer-model)

Comment: you do need a custom loss function for something like that yes. That being said it is just calling an original loss + simple masking so it is a very thin wrapper that will not cost you anything performance wise

Comment: Reduction.NONE just means that no additional reduction is applied by the class wrapper. For categorical losses with an example input shape of [batch, W, H, n_classes] the n_classes dimension is reduced. For pointwise losses you must include a dummy axis so that [batch, W, H, 1] is reduced to [batch, W, H]. Without the dummy axis [batch, W, H] will be incorrectly reduced to [batch, W].